# How to Get Autocomplete with Several Words

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using autocomplete on a field in Azure Search... it works great, however I want the autocomplete results to return the next "x" number of words (like in the following screenshot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-suggesters)

I've tried all three Autocomplete types "oneTerm", "twoTerms" and "oneTermWithContext" however none of those give me the expected results.

I expect to type "tom clan" and autocomplete should return "tom clancys rainbow six siege"

Answer (score 2):

Excellent point about the documentation showing several words in the example and the autocomplete API only supporting up to two terms ahead.  I think we should update the example to better reflect the actual behavior of the API.

If you are interested, please create a feedback item for the API enhancement you suggested so it can collect some votes: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

Thanks!
Mike Carter
Azure Search product team